# How to send a tweet from PHP with OAuth?

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

There's a few tutorials and classes out there but they no longer appear to work since Twitter changed to oAuth.

How do I send a tweet from PHP, in the most basic way possible?

For example, the 'old' way using the MyTwitter class was as follows:

```
require_once('MyTwitter.class.php');
$twitter =  new MyTwitter('username', 'password');
$message = "API Test.";
$result = $twitter->updateStatus($message);
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The demo didn't work, but the class itself did-

```
    $connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_SECRET);
    $content = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials');
    $result = $connection->post('statuses/update', array('status' => $message));
```

Answer (score 2):

Theres a [good walkthrough here](http://shiflett.org/blog/2010/sep/twitter-oauth) of implementing Twitter OAuth, complete with a working demo. If you're already using a framework you probably have other options also such as `Zend_Service_Twitter` in Zend Framework

Comment: Unfortunately the working demo doesn't work. It's not passing through the oauth token.